# Merge xml tag value by command-line

Tags: awk, sed, xmlstarlet

I am trying to merge publisher and isbn value into title tag using sed. But I can't find any example here that match my requirement. example as below

from this

```
<book>
  <title>The Big Book of Silly Jokes for Kids</title>
  <publisher>Rockridge Press</publisher>
  <isbn>ISBN-10</isbn>
</book>
```

to this

```
<book>
  <title>[Rockridge Press ISBN-10] The Big Book of Silly Jokes for Kids</title>
  <publisher>Rockridge Press</publisher>
  <isbn>ISBN-10</isbn>
</book>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: You should use a xslt processor or another XML-aware tool instead of trying to use `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xml ed -u /book/title -x "concat('[',/book/publisher/text(),' ',/book/isbn,'] ',/book/title)" book.xml
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book>
  <title>[Rockridge Press ISBN-10] The Big Book of Silly Jokes for Kids</title>
  <publisher>Rockridge Press</publisher>
  <isbn>ISBN-10</isbn>
</book>
```

EDIT: space added after ']'
The '--inplace' is optional to 'edit file inplace'.

Answer (score 1):

The command line to modify nodes in an XML file can be xmlstarlet, as you say.

You can also write an XSL program, as follows:

**book.xsl**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="title"><!-- the node you want to modify -->
    <title>
      <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../publisher/text()"/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../isbn/text()"/>
      <xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../title/text()"/>
    </title>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!-- identity transformation for remaining nodes -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Assuming your original file is called `book.xml`, the XSL program above can be invoked running at the command line:

```sh
xsltproc book.xsl book.xml
```